# Does anyone know how to call Values from Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to call the Values from the Array to print (in Java, I'm using Eclipse)

- The user is presented with the first screen which has a list of 10 destinations e.g. (1) Spain (2) France
- After selecting the destination the user is presented with a list of 10 hotels
- After the hotels the number of weeks required is presented (keep it simple 1, 2, or 3 weeks)
  *After the duration the party numbers are selected, how many at 12 years and under (%50 off per person) and how many 13 + full price passengers
- On completion of the above a full breakdown will be displayed on the screen and a book option will be given
- The system must be in a loop so orders can be taken all day, but at any point entering -99 will end the application.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TravelAgent 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int country_choice; 
        int country_prices;
        int user_selecction;
        int country_length;
        int countrylength; 
        int x;

        String[] country = 

            {
                "Greece","Spain","France","Russia","Italy","Mexico","Germany","Maldives","Thailand","Portugal"
            };

        int [] country_prices_1 = 

            {
                300,400,200,500,250,800,450,900,750,350
            };

        String[] hotels_greece =
            {
                "Lindos Blu","Saint Andrea","The Excelsior","Elite Suites","Avithos","New Hotel","The Met Hotel",
                "TesoroBlu Hotel & Spa","Mykonos Grand Hotel","Achtis Hotel"
            };

        String[] hotels_spain =
            {
                "Alma Barcelona", "Seaside Grand Hotel Residencia", "Hotel Primero Perimera", "Valbusenda Resort",
                "Hotel Maria Cristina", "Gran Hotel La Perla", "El Palace Hotel",
                "Tinas de Pechon", "Dream Hotel Gran Tacande", "Protur Palmeras Playa"
            };

        String[] hotels_france =
            {
                "Le Bristol Paris", "Hotel Plaza Athenee","Hotel Fabric","La Maison Favart","Hotel Le Six",
                "Hotel Royal Riviera", "Hotel Crillon Le Brave", "Mandarin Oriental", "Le Mareuil", "Hotel d’Europe"
            };

        String[] hotels_russia =
            {
                "Lotte Hotel Moscow", "Old Estate Hotel & SPA","Pushka Inn Hotel","The Ritz-Carlton Moscow","Mercure Arbat Moscow",
                "Belmond Grand Hotel Europe", "Ararat Park Hyatt Moscow", ".Astoria Hotel", "Helvetia Hotel", "Katerina City Hotel"
            };
        String[] hotels_italy =
            {
                "Hotel Monika", "Bellevue Syrene","Hotel Ai Reali","Hotel Belvedere","Hotel Buca di Bacco",
                "Petronilla Hotel", "Santa Caterina Hotel", "Color Hotel", "Belmond Grand Hotel Timeo", "Antiche Mura Hotel"
            };

        String[] hotels_mexico =
            {
                "Rosewood Mayakoba", "Hotel Jashita","Villa La Estancia","Capella Ixtapa","Banyan Tree Cabo Marques",
                "The Beloved Hotel", "Casa Misha", "Esperanza", "Excellence Playa Mujeres", "La Casa Que Canta"
            };

        String[] hotels_germany =
            {
                "Swissotel Dresden", "Mandarin Oriental","Park Hyatt Hamburg","Steigenberger Grandhotel Handelshof",
                "Hotel Villa Hugel", "Sonnenalp Resort", "Hezelhof Hotel", "Das Stue", "Gutshaus Stolpe", "Hotel Edelweiss"
            };

        String[] hotels_maldives =
            {
                "Baros Maldives","Soneva Fushi Resort","Constance Moofushi","Taj Exotica Resort & Spa","Mirihi Island Resort",
                "Lily Beach Resort & Spa","Naladhu Resort","Veligandu Island Resort","Cocoa Island Resort","Six Senses Laamu"
            };

        String[] hotels_thailand =
            {
                "Dhara Devi Chiang Mai","Oriental Residence","Layana Resort & Spa","Beyond Resort Khaolak","Sunsuri Phuket",
                "Rimping Village","Rabbit Resort","The Siam","The Peninsula",".Pimalai Resort & Spa"

            };

        String[] hotels_portugal =
            {
                "The Cliff Bay","Conrad Algarve","Bristania Hotel","Olissippo Lapa Palace","Quinta Jardins de Lago","The Yeatman",
                "Altis Belem Hotel & Spa","Quinta da Bela Vista","Hotel Santa Justa","Hotel Belavista da Luz"
            };

        int [] hotel_prices_greece =
            {
                70,90,100,140,80,75,200,110,160,230
            };

        int [] hotel_prices_spain =
            {
                50,70,90,100,120,140,160,180,200,230
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_france =
            {
                60,60,70,75,80,90,105,120,140,200
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_russia =
            {
                80,90,90,95,100,110,130,150,175,190
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_italy =
            {
                80,85,90,100,115,130,140,220,235,240
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_mexico =
            {
                200,240,260,275,300,360,375,380,395,450
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_germany =
            {
                60,65,70,85,100,120,150,180,220,210
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_maldives =
            {
                260,280,300,350,380,400,440,450,550,580
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_thailand =
            {
                245,255,270,290,300,350,365,370,390,400
            };
        int [] hotel_prices_portugal =
            {
                110,115,120,120,140,150,180,185,250,260
            };
        System.out.println("please select your holiday destination");
        System.out.println("************************************");
        System.out.println("*      Want to book a holiday?     *");
        System.out.println("*                                  *");
        System.out.println("*     You're at the right place    *");
        System.out.println("*                                  *");
        System.out.println("************************************");
        System.out.println("* Please choose from the following *");
        System.out.println("*           1.Greece               *");
        System.out.println("*           2.Spain                *");
        System.out.println("*           3.France               *");
        System.out.println("*           4.Russia               *");
        System.out.println("*           5.Italy                *");
        System.out.println("*           6.Mexico               *");
        System.out.println("*           7.Germany              *");
        System.out.println("*           8.Maldives             *");
        System.out.println("*           9.Thailand             *");
        System.out.println("*          10.Portugal             *");
        System.out.println("**  Enter Destination from 1-10   **");

        country_choice =keyboard.nextInt();

        For (int x = 0; x < country.price; x++) {

        }

        //country_choice = Integer.parseInt(user_selection.nextLine())-1;

        country_choice = Integer.parseInt(user_selection.nextLine())-1;

        System.out.println("country[x]" + "country_prices[x]" );



        //“+ country [country_choice]+ country prices [country_prices]+”.00”);

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from your array accesses; `"country[x]" + "country_prices[x]"` should be `country[x] + country_prices[x]`.  So long as one of those types is a `String`, then the concatenation will just work.

Comment: Why are you using so many arrays? Couldn't you create a hotel object and have an array of hotels?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  It's not clear from your post what you're actually asking about.

Comment: you should take a look at `java.util.Map` (FWIW)

Comment: Guys, he obviously doesn't have much experience with programming. Using objects, maps etc. in this case will just worsen the situation. This looks a lot like a school assignment and one that probably has to teach working with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we begin:

- Like said in the comments, you should probably declare some classes and helper methods for that, but I'll assume you haven't reached this point yet so I'll do everything in `main`.
- The convention in Java is to use *camelCase*, but since you are using *snake_case* I'll also use it in the example.
- I cut it down to 3 countries to make the example more compact.

Instead of having a separate variable for each country's hotels and hotel prices, you should use an array of arrays(AKA "two dimensional array"), where each entry in the array is another array. For example, *France* is  number 3 which means it's index is 2(array indices start from 0), so `hotels[2]` will be the array of the hotel names in France(instead of `hotels_france`). That way, if you have the country number in a variable, you can easily access that country's list of hotels without having to code for each country separately.

It goes something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TravelAgent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] countries = {
            "Greece", "Spain", "France"
        };

        int[] country_prices = {
            300, 400, 200
        };

        String[][] hotels = new String[3][];

        hotels[0] = new String[]{
            "Lindos Blu", "Saint Andrea", "The Excelsior", "Elite Suites", "Avithos", "New Hotel", "The Met Hotel",
            "TesoroBlu Hotel & Spa", "Mykonos Grand Hotel", "Achtis Hotel"
        };
        hotels[1] = new String[]{
            "Alma Barcelona", "Seaside Grand Hotel Residencia", "Hotel Primero Perimera", "Valbusenda Resort",
            "Hotel Maria Cristina", "Gran Hotel La Perla", "El Palace Hotel",
            "Tinas de Pechon", "Dream Hotel Gran Tacande", "Protur Palmeras Playa"
        };
        hotels[2] = new String[]{
            "Le Bristol Paris", "Hotel Plaza Athenee", "Hotel Fabric", "La Maison Favart", "Hotel Le Six",
            "Hotel Royal Riviera", "Hotel Crillon Le Brave", "Mandarin Oriental", "Le Mareuil", "Hotel d’Europe"
        };

        int[][] hotel_prices = new int[3][];
        hotel_prices[0] = new int[]{
            70, 90, 100, 140, 80, 75, 200, 110, 160, 230
        };
        hotel_prices[1] = new int[]{
            50, 70, 90, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 230
        };
        hotel_prices[2] = new int[]{
            60, 60, 70, 75, 80, 90, 105, 120, 140, 200
        };

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please select your holiday destination");
            for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; ++i) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + countries[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter destination from 1-" + countries.length);

            int country_choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (-99 == country_choice) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Chosen country: " + countries[country_choice - 1]);
            System.out.println("Country price: " + country_prices[country_choice - 1] + ".00");


            System.out.println("Please select your hotel");
            for (int i = 0; i < hotels[country_choice - 1].length; ++i) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + "." + hotels[country_choice - 1][i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter hotel from 1-" + hotels[country_choice - 1].length);

            int hotel_choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (-99 == hotel_choice) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Chosen hotel: " + hotels[country_choice - 1][hotel_choice - 1]);
            System.out.println("Hotel price: " + hotel_prices[country_choice - 1][hotel_choice - 1] + ".00");
        }
    }
}
```